# How to loop two array with smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

I'm trying to make a simple forum script, based on smarty.

On the front page I want to be able to display every category, and the forums linked to those categories.

For this I have two tables on my database, "forums" and "forums_categories".

```
Forums table:
+----+---------+-------------+
| id | value   | category_id |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  1 | Forum 1 | 1           |
|  2 | Forum 2 | 2           |
|  3 | Forum 3 | 1           |
|  4 | Forum 4 | 2           |
+----+---------+-------------+

forum_categories table:
+----+------------+
| id | value      |
+----+------------+
|  1 | Category 1 |
|  2 | Category 2 |
+----+------------+
```

This is my PHP code

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `forums_categories` ORDER BY `id` ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $category = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $cat_id = $row['id'];
            $category[] = $row;

            # Get forums
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `forums` WHERE category_id='$cat_id'";
            $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

            $forums = array();
            while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
            { 
                $forums[] = $row2;
            }

        }
    }

    $smarty->assign('category', $category);
    $smarty->assign('forums', $forums);
```

This is what I have on my forum.tpl file.

```
        {section name=i loop=$category}
        <li>{$category[i].id} - {$category[i].value}</li>

        {section name=o loop=$forums}
            <li>{$forums[o].category_id} - {$forums[o].value}</li>
        {/section}

        {/section}
```

I want to get this:

1 - Category 1
1 - Forum 1
1 - Forum 3

2 - Category 2
2 - Forum 2
2 - Forum 4

but instead I'm getting this:

1 - Category 1
2 - Forum 2
2 - Forum 4

2 - Category 2
2 - Forum 2
2 - Forum 4

(Notice how on Category 1 I'm getting the forums with category_id 2 instead of 1)

What's wrong with my code? If anyone can help point me in the right direction I would be most thankful.

Comment: You can try to assign `$forums` with `ID` for parent category `$forums[$cat_id] = $row2;` and then loop in smarty with that `ID`: `{section name=o loop=$forums[$category[i].id]}`

Comment: I tried that but then it just shows the categories and no forums. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$forums = array();
```

before next code.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

and must change section of forums

```
{section name=o loop=$forums}
  {if $forums[o].category_id==$category[i].id}
    <li>{$forums[o].category_id} - {$forums[o].value}</li>
  {/if}
{/section}
```

but Not tested.